getting the state of an image with gsap flip before remvoing the class
I'm trying to do an image expanding effect on scroll with gsap scrolltrigger and flip plugin, here is the original code with vanilla js expaning image it does seem that the everything is working fine except when i add the line to remove the class the flip state does not capture the initial state of the image, I assume because i add and remove the class quickly
here is what I want to achieve ( sorry for the quality)

I did some debugging I'm sure the problem is the initial state of the image, and some times it works randomly and when i refresh the effect goes away again
the closest I think it has something to do with the way I'm adding and removing the type--open class
'use client'
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger'
import { Flip } from 'gsap/dist/Flip'
import "./globals.css";

export default function Home() {

  const wrapElementRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null); 
  const imageRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null); 
  const textRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, Flip);

    const wrapElement = wrapElementRef.current;
    const imageElement = imageRef.current;
    const textBlock = textRef.current
      // Temporarily add the 'type--open' class to capture the final state
      wrapElement.classList.add('type--open');

      // Get the flip state
      const flipstate = Flip.getState([imageElement, textBlock], {
        props: 'transform'
      });


      wrapElement.classList.remove('type--open');
      
      // Create the Flip animation timeline
      Flip.to(flipstate, {
        ease: 'sine.inOut',
        simple: true,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: wrapElement,
          start: 'center bottom',
          end: 'center top',
          scrub: true,
        }
      });
    
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="box"></div>
      <div className="content content--center">
          <h3 className="meta">Project 2</h3>
          <h2 ref={wrapElementRef} className="type">
              Life is a wild journey;<br />
              embrace the<br />
              <span className="type__expand type__expand--reveal type__expand--center">
                <span className="aright">detours </span>
                <span ref={imageRef} className="type__expand-img" >
                  <span className="type__expand-img-inner" style={{backgroundImage: "url(/img/2.jpg)"}}></span>
                </span>
                <span ref={textRef} className="anim skewed" >and dance</span>
              </span>
              <br />
              under the stars.
          </h2>
        </div>
    </main>
  );
}

